# Azure B2C App Registration Scope - Can't Change "Who Can Consent" To Admins and Users

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to follow tutorial to add a scope that admins and users can consent, but I don't see the option to change "Who Can Consent" to admins and users - what am I missing?

#8 here:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2/blob/master/1.%20Desktop%20app%20calls%20Web%20API/README-incremental.md

also no details given here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-expose-web-apis

thanks

[image]

Users are allowed to consent to any app in the Enterprise Applications -> Consent and Permissions settings...

[image]

Comment: Does Carl's answer useful to you ? If also have any questions, you can tell us. If his solution helps you, you can mark his answer as [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), you can help more forum users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Azure AD B2C** expose API application **only supports admin consent**, and does **not support user consent** permissions. Only the api application exposed by **Azure AD** can choose user consent. You refer to the documentation of Azure AD rather than the documentation of Azure AD B2C. There are many documents applicable to Azure ad b2c, such as: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-web-api-dotnet?tabs=app-reg-ga#configure-scopes) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-single-page-app-webapi?tabs=app-reg-ga#configure-scopes) and [here](https://daniel-krzyczkowski.github.io/Cars-Island-ASP-NET-Core-API-Secured-By-Azure-AD-B2C/).

For your second doubt:

> Users are allowed to consent to any app in the Enterprise Applications
> -> Consent and Permissions settings....

What is said in the portal is not rigorous, the [complete description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-user-consent?tabs=azure-portal#user-consent-settings) should be: **This option allows all users to consent to any permission which doesn't require admin consent, for any application.**  It just means that the user can consent to permissions that do not require the administrator's consent, not that the user can consent to any permissions.

Comment: thank you Carl. actually this is a better tutorial for what I am trying to do: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi/